# How to read a line from a filehandle in a hashref

Tags: perl, href, filehandle

I have a handle to a socket in an hashref:  `$self->{socket}`.
I want to read from it using `$line = <$self->{socket}>`, but I get a syntax error.

Now, I know that

```
print {$self->{socket}} "Hello";
```

Will take care of printing, but

```
$line = < {$self->{socket}} >;
```

Doesn't work.

How do I do this without cluttering up my code like this:

```
$fh = $self->{socket};
$line = < $fh >;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `<fh>` is short for `readline(fh)`
- `<$fh>` is short for `readline($fh)`
- `<...>` is short for `glob(qq<...>)`

The shortcut is out of the question, so use the long form.

```
readline($self->{socket})
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `readline`, as noted at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=776168 it still assigns to `$_` and checks it is defined.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'while (readline($fh)) {}'
while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) {
    ();
}
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: I really wish I could give both of you a green check.  You've both taught me something meaningful about PERL.

Comment: @Vic K, The name of the language is Perl, not PERL.